# What is the difference between rebasing one-commit branch on master HEAD + moving HEAD, and cherry-picking this one-commit change to master HEAD?

Tags: git

Supposing I have a squashed branch from the trunk - just one commit.
Now I want to put it on top of the current master HEAD.
I may either:

- switch to master HEAD
- cherry-pick the change

or

- rebase the change on master HEAD (one commit rebase)
- move master HEAD to this new commit

Both should bring the same result. But is any of them less troublesome in case of conflicts? Does git do underneath the same operation during the one-commit rebase and cherry-pick operation?

Comment: Yeah, conflicts will be presented and resolved similarly, there should not be any significative difference between the processes you describe. The rebase feature is just doing cherry-picks in the background anyway.

Comment: What is the trunk?

Comment: I want to point out that the single most troublesome contributing factor in what you describe is the squashing of a branch into one single commit. That just invites rebase conflicts. By all means performing an unlimited amount of `fixup` and `squash` in interactive rebase during development is perfectly fine (almost required), but to then as a final step discard all separation of changes is extremely counter productive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are functionally 100% identical. As far as the merge logic is concerned, rebase *is* cherry-pick.

The only difference is what happens to the branch pointers afterwards, and you are moving the `master` pointer manually yourself afterwards (in your second example) to compensate. The only remaining difference is that in your first (cherry-pick) example the squashed branch pointer doesn't move, whereas in your second (rebase) example the squashed branch pointer moves to coincide with where you are then putting the `master` pointer.

To put it another way, when you rebase, unless you first make a temporary branch at that point, you lose the reachability of the unrebased version of the branch; whereas, when you cherry-pick, you don't lose any reachability.

Before:

```
A -- B -- C (master)
      \
       D (branch)
```

After, example 1:

```
A -- B -- C -- D' (master)
      \
       D (branch)
```

After, example 2:

```
A -- B -- C -- D' (master, branch)
      \
       D
```